# Page not found by django urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

This my django urls

```
path('count/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', CountlListView.as_view()),
```

This my my view

```
class CountlListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CountSerializers

    def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
        queryset=Count.objects.all()
        userId=self.request.query_params.get('id')
        print(userId)
        return queryset.filter(userId=userId)
```

and this is my models

```
class Count(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channelId = models.ForeignKey(News_Channel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to filter content based on user Id but with my code, I am getting a page not found. Please help me to figure out to filter data by user id.

Comment: You mixed up `url(..)` and `path(..)`, the path should be `path('count/<int:pk>',...)`

Comment: Thanks, sir. It is working fine now.

Comment: You can use `re_path` if you want to follow the older regex style or even the `url` way works fine due to backward compatibility. But mixing them will not work.

Comment: please add an answer describing the solution and resolve it, if it's working fine.